# how do i get cumulative sum in SQL workbench

Tags: mysql

i'm working on project right now, i use MySQL workbench for this project.

so, i have this table

```
ID Item   Item     In    
001       shirt    10
```

this is the query syntax:

```
 UPDATE tbitem SET itemIN = '"+itemIN+"' WHERE (`IDItem` = '"+IDItem+"')
```

everytime i input value in "In" column, it just replace the value. The value not added from the previous value

does anyone knows the syntax to get cumulative value ?

i would be appriciate it.

Answer (score 0):

you are not possible to do it using update statement. Better if you try with

first get the value in the table

select itemIN from tblitem.

after that you can add new value to the value get it from the table. Thats the simplest way to reach it. or if you use procedure, you can do it simply.